# Exporting WAR from Maven Source files - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, war

I am an absolute Java noob so please be kind. I moved to Java web development from PHP recently.

I have Java source code which contains looks like this:

`src` directory which has `.java` files

`rsc` directory which has hibernate xml files

`log4jcnf` configuration file for log4j

`pom.xml` file with libraries listed.

`WebContent` directory

`build.xml` & a `javadoc.xml`

Now I would like to export a war file and deploy it on a remote server.

How do I import the code into eclipse, and download the library files and eventually export a WAR file.

I understand these are very trivial questions, but all the resources online assume that the reader is a java developer.

What I have tried so far:

1. "Open projects from file system" - I locate the "Import Source" and Finish but nothing happens.
2. New "Dynamic Web project" - I uncheck "use default location" and select the location where my project files are and I get an error

"A project already exists on the file system at this location: /home/path/to/webservice.  Either use "Import Existing Projects into Workspace" to create a project at this location or delete the contents of /home/path/to/webservice from the file system."

Comment: `mvn clean package` - look in the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

It might be good idea to read these short tutorials, in case you are new to *Java Web Development* as well as to *Maven*.

- [Maven for building Java applications - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheMaven/article.html)
- [Using Maven within the Eclipse IDE - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html)
- [Introduction to Java Web development - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaWebTerminology/article.html)
- [Java web development with Eclipse WTP - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html)